# How to get a boolean variable DEBUG in a Freemarker?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, freemarker

How to find out if a project is in debug mode and get a variable of a logical type in the freemarker template.

Example:

```
    <#if (DEBUG)??>
        <script src="/static/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <#else>
        <script src="/static/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </#if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the same using the equals operator:

```
<#if DEBUG == true>
    <script src="/static/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<#else>
    <script src="/static/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
</#if>
```